# Waiting for Result from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, progressdialog

I want to start a ProgressDialog and a Broadcast Receiver (SMS_RECEIVED) from my activity. When a SMS received from a defined number it shiuld stop the Dialog and analyze the SMS Text.

In the Moment I have the Dialog and the Receiver, both works. When I dismiss the dialog it stops the Receiver.

But how can I make it works, that the Dialog close, when the SMS receiving and give the SMS Text to the activity?

The ProgressDialog in my Activity:

```
    protected void sendSMS(String sms){
        try {
            final ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, IncomingSms.class);
            final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


            waitSms = new ProgressDialog(this);
            waitSms.setTitle("Warte auf Bestätigungs SMS");
            waitSms.setCancelable(false);
            waitSms.setMessage("Abbrechen setzt die Einstellung in der App auf inaktiv zurück. Nicht warten übernimmt die Einstellung in der App, wartet aber nicht weiter auf eine Bestätigungs SMS.");
            waitSms.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                    waitSms.dismiss();
                }
            });
            waitSms.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Nicht warten", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                    waitSms.dismiss();
                }
            });
            waitSms.show();
        }
```

My Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

You disabled the Receiver with your flag:

> PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED.

Instead try this:

> PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED

Then inside your Receiver onReceive, move the data to the Activity with Intent extras, and intercept them with onNewIntent().

After you send the data you can disable the Receiver if you want.

Comment: I enable the Receiver with COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED when I start the ProgressDialog. When the user abort the Dialog, doesn't matter if positiv or negative button, it stop the receiver (this is it like i want it). Now i want, thet the dialog also ends, when a SMS received from a defined number, the activity get notice from this and get the SMS text.

Comment: Then close the dialog in the onNewIntent() of the Activity after you send the data

Answer (score 1):

Just register another `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity via `registerReceiver` that will listen for you event, e.g. `com.example.SMS_PARSED`. Convert your SMS to `Parcelable`, put in a `Bundle` and send it to the receiver registered in your activity. There, in `onReceive` you will `dismiss` the progress.

Also, don't forget to put a timeout in case of some error so that user doesn't get blocked by your progress.